# MiniMax seems to be making all available moves

Tags: c#, xna, chess, minimax

I'm in the process of making a chess game using c# Monogame. Apologies in advance I'm new to programming so this might be a really stupid question. After the player makes their move, MiniMax is called however it seems to be making every available move rather than picking the one with the best evaluation. As far as I can tell, I think this might be an issue with the getallmoves function but I cant find the problem. It might be worth noting that PieceList is a list of all pieces left on the board, and Move is a class which contains the state of the board after the move has been made, and the evaluation for that board. Thanks in advance for any help it's much appreciated!

```
Board[intSelectedX, intSelectedY] = null;
Board[intX, intY] = strPieceSelected;
strPieceSelected = null;
PieceList[intIndex].intMoves += 1;

Board = MiniMax(Board, 1, true).newBoard;  

public Move MiniMax(string[,] board, int intDepth, bool booIsMaximising)
    {
    if (intDepth == 0)
    {
        return new Move(board, intEvaluateBoard(board));
    }

    if (booIsMaximising)
    {
        maxEval = -999999;
        BestMove = null;

        foreach (Move move in getAllMoves(board))
        {
            evaluation = MiniMax(move.newBoard, intDepth - 1, false).Eval;
            maxEval = Math.Max(evaluation, maxEval);

            if (maxEval == evaluation)
            {
                BestMove = move;
            }
        }

        return (new Move(BestMove.newBoard, maxEval));
    }
    else
    {
        minEval = 999999;
        BestMove = null;

        foreach (Move move in getAllMoves(board))
        {
            evaluation = MiniMax(move.newBoard, intDepth - 1, true).Eva
            minEval = Math.Min(evaluation, minEval);

            if (minEval == evaluation)
            {
                BestMove = move;
            }
        }

        return (new Move(BestMove.newBoard, minEval));
    }
}

public List<Move> getAllMoves(string[,] board_)
{
    List<Move> MovesList = new List<Move>();
    string [,] tempBoard;

    foreach (Piece piece in getAllPieces())
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if (board_[j, i] == strPiecesList[PieceList.IndexOf(piece)])
                {
                    intComputerX = j;
                    intComputerY = i;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                tempBoard = board_;
                Piece tempPiece = piece;

                if (isValidMove(j, i, intComputerX, intComputerY, PieceList.IndexOf(tempPiece)) == true)
                {
                    if ((tempBoard[j, i] == null) || (tempBoard[j, i] != null && PieceList[strPiecesList.IndexOf(tempBoard[j, i])].strColour == "White"))
                    {
                        if (tempBoard[j, i] != null)
                        {
                            tempBoard[j, i] = null;
                        }

                        tempBoard[j, i] = tempBoard[intComputerX, intComputerY];
                        tempBoard[intComputerX, intComputerY] = null;

                        MovesList.Add(new Move(tempBoard, intEvaluateBoard(tempBoard)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return MovesList;
}

public List<Piece> getAllPieces()
{
    List<Piece> PiecesList = new List<Piece>();

    foreach (Piece piece in PieceList)
    {
        if (piece.strColour == "Black")
        {
            PiecesList.Add(piece);
        }
    }

    return PiecesList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your getAllMoves does not work and it definitely does not produce legal chess moves.

It is very unusual to have a class holding both the gamestate and the evaluation. I would separate the evaluation to a simple function that returns a value. This is the normal way of doing it.

In the minimax loop you can either copy the board and make the move on a board copy, or you can make the move, evaluate and unmake the move. I can't see that you do any of those, you simply make all moves on the board?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, turns out in getallmoves when I reset tempboard to board_ tempboard was acting as a pointer so it wasn't resetting correctly and making multiple moves on one board.